# Google HTML interface in Sheets runs sometimes

Tags: html, google-apps-script, scriptlet

This HTML loads correctly and displays as intended. Two parts of it do not seem to work:

1. When I make any changes to any of the fields or add new household member information, the Save changes button does nothing (it does work if I only )
2. The head of household can't be changed.

In either of these cases, the button does absolutely nothing and does not call the either the htmlCloser or saveUpdate functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lexend' rel='stylesheet'>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Lexend';
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .row {
      display: flex;
    }

    .column {
      flex: 50%;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
  <form>
    <? let otherList = getOtherHHInfo(); ?>
    <? let hhList = getHHValues(null ,true); ?>
    <? let raceList = getRaces(); ?>
    <? let relationList = getRelations(); ?>
    <? let genderList = getGenders(); ?>
    <? let stateList = getStates(); ?>
    <? let sitchList = getLivingSitch(); ?>
    <h2>Household</h2>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
    <input name="email" <?= i ?> value="<?= otherList[0] ?>">
    <br>
    <label for="email" <?= i ?>>Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <input name="phone" <?= i ?> value="<?= otherList[1] ?>">
    <br>
    <label for="phone" <?= i ?>>Phone</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <input name="method" <?= i ?> value="<?= otherList[2] ?>">
    <br>
    <label for="method" <?= i ?>>Contact method</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <input name="language" <?= i ?> value="<?= otherList[3] ?>">
    <br>
    <label for="language" <?= i ?>>Language</label> 
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
    <input name="address" <?= i ?> value="<?= otherList[4] ?>">
    <br>
    <label for="address" <?= i ?>>Physical address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <input name="city" <?= i ?> value="<?= otherList[5] ?>">
    <br>
    <label for="city" <?= i ?>>City</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <input list="state" name="state" value="<?= otherList[6] ?>">
              <datalist id="state" >
                <? for (let j = 0; j < stateList.length; j++) { ?>
                  <option value="<?= stateList[j] ?>">
                <? } ?>
              </datalist>
    <br>
    <label for="state">State</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <input name="zip" <?= i ?> value="<?= otherList[7] ?>">
    <br>
    <label for="zip" <?= i ?>>ZIP</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <input name="addNotes" <?= i ?> value="<?= otherList[8] ?>">
    <br>
    <label for="addNotes" <?= i ?>>Address notes (directions)</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
    <input list="cws" name="cws" value="<?= otherList[9] ?>">
              <datalist id="cws" >
                  <option value="Yes">
                  <option value="No">  
              </datalist>
    <br>
    <label for="cws">Active CWS?</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <input list="dv" name="dv" value="<?= otherList[10] ?>">
              <datalist id="dv" >
                  <option value="Yes">
                  <option value="No">  
              </datalist>
    <br>
    <label for="dv">Fleeing DV?</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <input list="pregnant" name="pregnant" value="<?= otherList[11] ?>">
              <datalist id="pregnant" >
                  <option value="Yes">
                  <option value="No">  
              </datalist>
    <br>
    <label for="pregnant">Anyone pregnant?</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <input list="livingSituation" name="livingSituation" value="<?= otherList[12] ?>">
              <datalist id="livingSituation" >
                <? for (let s = 0; s < sitchList.length; s++) { ?>
                  <option value="<?= sitchList[s] ?>">
                <? } ?>
              </datalist>
    <br>
    <label for="livingSituation" <?= i ?>>Current living situation</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <input list="employed" name="employed" value="<?= otherList[13] ?>">
              <datalist id="employed" >
                  <option value="Yes">
                  <option value="No">  
              </datalist>
    <br>
    <label for="employed">Employed?</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>People</h2>
        <? for (let i = 0; i <= (hhList[0].length + 2); i++) { ?>
        <? try {?>
        <? if (!hhList[5][i].includes('.')) { ?>
          <p><b>Head of household</b></p>
        <? } else { ?>
          <p><b>Household member #<?= i ?></b></p>
        <? } ?>
        <? } catch { ?>
          <p><b>Household member #<?= i ?></b></p>
        <? } ?>
        <? if (i % 2 == 0){ ?>
        <div class="row" style="background-color:#cccccc;">
          <? } else { ?>
          <div class="row" style="background-color:#eeeeee;">
            <? } ?>
            <div class="column">
              <input name="firstName" value="<?= hhList[0][i] ?>">
              <br>
              <label for="firstName">First name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <input name="lastName" value="<?= hhList[6][i] ?>">
              <br>
              <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <input type="date" name="dob" value="<?= hhList[1][i] ?>">
              <br>
              <label for="dob" <?= i ?>>DOB</label>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <input list="race" name="race" value="<?= hhList[2][i] ?>">
              <datalist id="race" >
                <? for (let j = 0; j < raceList.length; j++) { ?>
                  <option value="<?= raceList[j] ?>">
                <? } ?>
              </datalist>
              <br>
              <label for="race" <?= i ?>>Race</label>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <input list="gender" name="gender" value="<?= hhList[3][i] ?>">
              <datalist id="gender" >
                <? for (let j = 0; j < raceList.length; j++) { ?>
                  <option value="<?= genderList[j] ?>">
                <? } ?>
              </datalist>
              <br>
              <label for="gender" <?= i ?>>Gender</label>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <input list="relation" name="relation" value="<?= hhList[4][i] ?>">
              <datalist id="relation" >
                <? for (let j = 0; j < relationList.length; j++) { ?>
                  <option value="<?= relationList[j] ?>">
                <? } ?>
              </datalist>
              <br>
              <label for="relation" <?= i ?>>Relationship</label>
            </div>
            </div>
            <? if (i == 0) { ?>
            <input type="radio" name="setHoH" value="<?= i ?>" checked="checked"> Keep <?= hhList[0][i] ?> as head of household?
            <hr>
            <? } else { ?>
              <? try { ?>  
              <? if (hhList[5][i].includes('~')) { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?= i ?>"> Re-include <?= hhList[0][i] ?> in household?
                <input type="radio" name="setHoH" value="<?= i ?>"> Make <?= hhList[0][i] ?> head of household?
                <hr>
              <? } else { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?= i ?>"> Remove <?= hhList[0][i] ?> from household?
                <input type="radio" name="setHoH" value="<?= i ?>"> Make <?= hhList[0][i] ?> head of household?
                <hr>
              <? } ?>
              <? } catch { ?>
                <input type="radio" name="setHoH" value="<?= i ?>"> Make <?= hhList[0][i] ?> head of household?
                <hr>
            <? } ?>
            <? } ?>
            <? } ?>
              <input type="submit" id="members" value="Save changes" onclick="saveUpdatePop()">
              <input type="submit" id="Cancel" value="Reset" onclick="resetUpdatePop()">
  </form>
  <script>
    function saveUpdatePop() {
      let firstNames = new Array;
      let dobs = new Array;
      let races = new Array;
      let genders = new Array;
      let relations = new Array;
      let lastNames = new Array;
      let otherInfo = new Array;
      let removeMe = new Array;
      let newHead = document.querySelector('input[name="setHoH"]:checked').value;
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("phone")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("method")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("language")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("address")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("city")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("state")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("zip")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("addNotes")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("cws")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("dv")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("pregnant")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("livingSituation")[0].value);
      otherInfo.push(document.getElementsByName("employed")[0].value);
      for (k = 0; k < document.getElementsByName("firstName").length; k++){
        firstNames.push(document.getElementsByName("firstName")[k].value);
        dobs.push(document.getElementsByName("dob")[k].value);
        races.push(document.getElementsByName("race")[k].value);
        genders.push(document.getElementsByName("gender")[k].value);
        relations.push(document.getElementsByName("relation")[k].value);
        lastNames.push(document.getElementsByName("lastName")[k].value);
        removeMe.push(document.querySelector('input[name="checkbox"]:checked').value);
      }
      if (removeMe.includes(newHead)) {
        return;
      }
      google.script.run.htmlCloser();
      google.script.run.saveUpdate(firstNames, dobs, races, genders, relations, otherInfo, lastNames, removeMe, newHead);
    }
    function resetUpdatePop() {
      google.script.run.updateHHInfo();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It functions perfectly if I use the checkboxes that allow me to remove or re-include a household member. The Reset button also function perfectly.

I've tried checking logs to see that it isn't getting to the function calls. I've run this multiple times. I'm at a completely loss as to why it runs under some circumstances and not the others. I have no idea what I'm missing at this point and would appreciate another set of eyes. Thanks!

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, about your current issue of `In either of these cases, the button does absolutely nothing and does not call the either the htmlCloser or saveUpdate functions.`, if `if (removeMe.includes(newHead)) { return; }` is the reason for your current issue, how about modifying it for your actual situation? But, if I misunderstood your situation and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for the suggestion. I found the issue. The removeMe.push(document.querySelector('input[name="checkbox"]:checked').value) would not allow the script to run if none of the values were checked. Seems to be working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The removeMe.push(document.querySelector('input[name="checkbox"]:checked').value) would not allow the script to run if none of the values were checked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).